# Using Dynamic Libraries in QT Creator Project

Tags: c++, cmake, dynamic-library

I want to use the Ubunut/Linux Library libglfw (Glfw) with a Standard C++ Project, that uses CMake in Qt Creator. How do I do that? How do I have to include the Linked Library?

Edit:
Actually I Include the libglfw (/usr/lib/lglfw.so) like

```
#include "GL/glfw.h" //That line works
int main(void) {
 GLFWwindow* window; //Just like in the GLFW-Example
 ...
}
```

And I get the error "GLFWwindow was not declared in this scope" and similar errors for each glfw-call

Comment: there is no such thing as `GLFWwindow` in the version of glfw of the current Ubuntu repo. Refer to the [documentation here](http://www.glfw.org/GLFWReference27.pdf) to see how to deal with glfw 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just edit the `CMakeLists.txt` of your project like you would with any other CMake project. Qt Creator doesn't add any complexity on top of it.

For Glfw you should only have to add

```
FIND_PACKAGE (glfw REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (${PROJECT_NAME} ${GLFW_LIBRARY})
```

Note that that `${PROJECT_NAME}` is the default that is added in Qt Creator, it just needs to be whatever the first parameter of the `add_executable()` call is (of course of the executable that you want to link glfw to).

after that you should be able to just grab the code example at the end of the [getting started page](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/quick.html) of glfw and compile that within your project without a problem to test if it worked.

Comment: Well.. I don't want to download the Source... I just want to use the glfw version, that you get when you type sudo apt-get install libglfw* Is that the Same? How do I include that library in c? with #include <lib> or with #include "lib"?

Comment: @Tobi you don't need the source, just the regular and the `-dev` package that contains the include files. Doing the `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` is necessary (and depends on the version of glfw you use), just like in the example I linked to. But that only takes care of pulling in the definitions for the compilation. You still need to link it regardless. Which packages exactly you need depends on your distro and version. In Ubuntu 13.04 it's `apt-get install glfw2 glfw-dev` and for the header `#include "GL/glfw.h`. It's version 2.7.2-1 in the repo currently, keep that in mind when looking for docs